# API must return less than 400 characters

Tags: javascript, twitch

I have created this Javascript inside of HTML and my friend has hosted it. It works perfectly so I am assuming it is nothing to do with the code:

```
var deaths = [
    "with a potato.",
    "by using a truck and running them over.",
    "with a gun, bang bang.",
    "by stuffing a mouldy lemon in their mouth.",
    "by throwing multiple knives at them.",
    "by throwing them off a building onto a cactus.",
    "by tying them up and forgetting about them.",
    "by using mind control and making them walk into lava."
    //"",
    //"",
    //"",
    //"",
    //"",
    //"",
    //"",
    //"",
    //"",
    //"",
    //"",
    //"",
    //"",
    //"",
];
var death = deaths[Math.floor(Math.random() * deaths.length)];
document.write(death)
```

I am making a command for nightbot, a bot for twitch tv and in the command it pulls the text from the webpage made with the javascipt above. I am using this `$(customapi URL)` in the command with the websites url where it says URL but when the command is run it returns '[API must return less than 400 characters]'.

Comment: It's unlikely that the bot can actually parse JavaScript, so it sees only your code which is more than 400 characters. You need to do this on the server.

Comment: _with a potato_  - Brilliant. :D

Comment: Why don't you handle deaths on the server? It is safer and sounder.